# cakeRequest resulting in "Undefined property" error

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am working with a request object:

```
$this->request
```

and received the following error:

```
Undefined property: EventsController::$request
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you certain you are running Cake 2.0 and not 1.3? What's the output of `Configure::version()`?

Cake only throws this error when the property is actually undefined. In 2.0 you should get a fully populated request object. Using `$this->request` in 1.3 throws the error you're receiving.